# PassportJS + JWT - Proper Authentication and Authorizarion?

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, passport.js, passport-local

Good morning/afternoon/evening!

Having recently started a little Project for myself, one of the first things I wanted to do is the Login/Authentication and permission to access different routes/Authorization.

I am currently using:

- NodeJS
- Express
- Passport (+ Passport Local and Passport JWT)
- jsonwebtoken

The goal of my Server is to receive a Stateless Authentication/Authorization System because I aim to bypass the "Single-Threaded"-Problem and use Node's Cluster Module to spawn a Process for each Thread.

I have already accomplished a basic authentication via a JSON Web Token and am currently storing only the UserID, iad and expiry date in it.

Now I was thinking about adding roles to have an "easy" check if the user was allowed into certain routes or not, but there was where my problems started.
Assuming I add roles into the token, I can easily verify if I am allowed to access that route or not using the JWTStrategy of Passport. 
But what if the roles have changed within the time the Token was issued, and the time the user tries to access a route he has no more permissions to? As of now, he would probably be able to still access that route because the JWT'S receive (obviously) no instant update of the roles.
Same goes for a banned/suspended user, he would still be able to use the site as normal, until the token expires and he needs to request a new one.

This until now reflects the strategy of not querying the DB after the login anymore for user information, since the JWTs are used to store the most critical data (Not user sensitve ones though).

Invalidating the Token could easily work via JTI's (TokenID in the Token) which are stored in the Database, and once the TokenID is said to be "banned" or anything, I'd simply not let the token authenticate anymore. But this adds a database call per API call...

For Roles/Permission verification, the way I see it right now as well is that I would not get around one Database call per API call to check for user rights.

I know that there are solutions like Node-ACL or CASL, but they are either In-Memory which I can't use because I would love to not rely on Memory because I am Clustering, or even Dockerizing my Application, and I don't wanna be "only" depending on Redis or MongoDB - I'd like my application to be pretty flexible when it comes to Databases.

I also know that there are Strategies like "Refresh" and "Access" Tokens, where the Refresh Token is long-lived and the Acecss-Token is short-lived (e.g. a Expiry Date of 15 Minutes) - Is this a suitable strategy? The Ban/Suspension or RoleChange would still not be instant. I could keep the Refresh and Access Token in the Database and Invalidate the Access-Token once critical data of that user changes, and let the CLient/Website figure out that the AccessToken is gone and require a new one... But this seems like a huge overhead to me...

**Summary**

I am using JsonWebToken to Authenticate the user. My problem is that I am not getting around a Database Query per API Call of the User because I don't have critical info always updated in the JWT (User Banned/Suspended, Roles).

What is the best thing for me to do in this Situation?